# Spring Cloud Sleuth different trace-ID integrate with pubsub: not propogating same trace-id in one call

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth, google-cloud-logging, spring-cloud-gcp

I have my applications running on `GCP cloudrun`. One of the services consumes an event on the `pubsub` topic, and then processes it, and calls another service via the `REST` end point.

We have used below dependencies which is responsible to handle the `trace-id` in `REST` and `pubsub` call.

```
implementation("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-trace")
implementation("com.google.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub")

and below configuration:

spring.cloud.gcp.trace.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gcp.trace.pubsub.enabled=true
```

But what I can see is different `trace-id` in log statement of both the services.

Ex: If service 1 which is consuming event from `pubsub` has `trace-id` "4b7f76b538f9211acf648dc2049c4add", then service 2 which is getting called by service 1 should have same `trace-id`, but this is not happening. Service 2 has different trace-id.

Can someone please suggest here what could be the resolution here.

I tried using different versions of dependency `spring-cloud-gcp-trace` but did not get any result.